# Merge two different dataframes on different column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I have two dataframes,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['121', '345', '123', '146'],
                     'C': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A3'],
                      'BB': ['B0', 'B3'],
                      'CC': ['121', '345'],
                      'DD': ['D0', 'D1']})
```

Now I need to get the similiar rows from column A and B from df1 and column A and CC from df2.
And so I tried possible merge options, such as:

```
both_DFS=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left',left_on=['A','B'],right_on=['A','CC'])
```

and this will not give me row information from df2 dataframe which is what I needed. Meaning, I have all column names from df2 but the rows are just empty or Nan.

And then I tried:

```
Both_DFs=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left',left_on=['A','B'],right_on=['A','CC'])[['A','B','CC']]
```

And this give me error as,

```
KeyError: "['B'] not in index"
```

I am aiming to have a merged Dataframe with all columns from both df1 and df2. Any suggestions would be great

Desired output:

```
 Both_DFs
    A   B   C   BB  CC  DD
0   A1  121 K0  B0  121 D0
```

So in my data frames (df1 and df2), only one row has exact match for both columns of interest. That is, Column A and B from df1 has only one row matching exactly to rows in columns A and CC in df2

Comment: What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` ? Problem is with real data only?

Comment: Because it seems there is some whitespace in column name only, for removing need `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: The Actual datafarme has another column name the df1 used in my question is dummy. So with my actual datafarme its print out, ['Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Annotation', 'Detailed Annotation', ' Description', ' Type']  for (df1.columns.tolist())

Comment: @jezrael I do Stripped while reading it in pd.read_csv itself for all columns and rows.

Comment: Super, still `KeyError`? Is possible problem in `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @j  print (df2.columns.tolist()) for second datafrme its , ['Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'chr', 'start', 'end', 'gene_sym', 'Lines'] giving me actual columns

Comment: Yes, but maybe problem is in `df2.columns` names, because `['Chr', 'Start', 'End', 'Annotation', 'Detailed Annotation', ' Description', ' Type']` seems nice.

Comment: How ? I mean I am wondering how does it make a problem while merging

Comment: I have no idea, becuse all seems nice. :(

Comment: In sample have `NaN` values, because no match in data. Try change `df2` - `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A2', 'A3'],
                      'BB': ['B0', 'B3'],
                      'CC': ['121', '345'],
                      'DD': ['D0', 'D1']})`

Comment: Well it didnt help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, if you declare column `A` as index, it works:

```
Both_DFs = pd.merge(df1.set_index('A', drop=True),df2.set_index('A', drop=True), how='left',left_on=['B'],right_on=['CC'], left_index=True, right_index=True).dropna().reset_index()
```

This results in:

```
    A    B   C  BB   CC  DD
0  A1  123  K0  B0  121  D0
1  A1  345  K1  B0  121  D0
2  A3  146  K1  B3  345  D1
```

**EDIT**

You just needed:

```
Both_DFs = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left',left_on=['A','B'],right_on=['A','CC']).dropna()
```

Which gives:

```
    A    B   C  BB   CC  DD
0  A1  121  K0  B0  121  D0
```

Comment: Its merging for right columns but the problem is same , The for the right dataframe here df2 the columns in Both_DFs is just empty or Nan. There are rows from the df1 got merged to Both_DFs dataframe, same as my above script. The columns from df2 are there but the rows just empty

Comment: Made an edit, seems to work :)

Comment: Yes, It worked :) Thank you

Comment: @zipa - I think `left_on=['B'],right_on=['CC']` can be removed also, because no match in `B` and `CC`. Can you also add your output?

Comment: @jezrael It can be removed in this case, but maybe OP has some data where it shouldn't be removed :)

Comment: @zipa - Hmmm, I thought first data are first join by indexes and then by `on` parameter, but it seems there is only match by `index`. So `on` can be removed. But if i am wrong, give me know. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael From my perspective only thing that bugs me is this 3rd row that doesn't look like it should be there. You explained why is it there, but I think it just shouldn't.

Comment: @zipa, But there is a problem.Its printing out the duplicated rows as well. Also, the merge is not based on the exact matching rows from both dataframes. Could you pease revise your code once more

Comment: Sure, I'm on it :)

Comment: @user1017373 - can you add desired output to question?

Comment: @jezreal, Sure added :)

Comment: @user1017373 Just `dropna()`, your join was fine.

Comment: No as you see there is 3 rows but there should have been only one in the real case. As in,  only one of it has exact matching rows as per condition. I have edited my question for more clarity. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Please look at the edit

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with default left join or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), last if necessary remove rows with `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df1.join(df2.set_index('A'), on='A').dropna())
    A    B   C  BB   CC  DD
0  A1  123  K0  B0  121  D0
1  A1  345  K1  B0  121  D0
3  A3  146  K1  B3  345  D1
```

---

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', how='left').dropna())
    A    B   C  BB   CC  DD
0  A1  123  K0  B0  121  D0
1  A1  345  K1  B0  121  D0
3  A3  146  K1  B3  345  D1
```

EDIT:

I think you need `inner join` (by default, so `on='inner'` can be omit):

```
Both_DFs = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=['A','B'],right_on=['A','CC'])
print (Both_DFs)
    A    B   C  BB   CC  DD
0  A1  121  K0  B0  121  D0
```

Comment: It seems you need only remove `how='left'` for default inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your example show exactly your problem but,

If we try to merge with MultiIndex, we need to have the 2 index matching.

df1['A'] == df2['A'] && df1['B'] == df2['CC']

Here we haven't any row that match the 2 index.

If we merge just by df1['A'], we got something like this : 
    Both_DFs=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['A'], right_on=['A'])

```
    A    B   C   BB   CC   DD
0  A1  123  K0   B0  121   D0
1  A1  345  K1   B0  121   D0
2  A2  121  K0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  A3  146  K1   B3  345   D1
```

If you wan't remove line row that not in df2 try to change 'how' method to inner.

```
Both_DFs=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['A'], right_on=['A'])
   A    B   C   BB   CC   DD
0  A1  123  K0   B0  121   D0
1  A1  345  K1   B0  121   D0
2  A3  146  K1   B3  345   D1
```

Did this approach of what you're looking for ?