# Combine Dataframes in Python with same and different Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have 2 dataframes I want to combine

dataframe 1 :

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| row2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

dataframe 2:

| ID | A | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

and I want them to merge and replace values of the same row to the values on dataframe 2 like this:

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 6 | 7 | 3 | 8 |
| row2 | 4 | 5 | 6 | null |

how do I do this? I tried merging and concatenation but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you

Comment: perhaps this one may help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43735493/3270433

Comment: @PrakashDahal this is just a sample, I need to use the code for much larger data that is always changing that need to replace data on rows and columns that already exist and add columns that aren't on the original dataframe

Answer (score 4):

Another method to merge your 2 dataframes:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('ID').last().reset_index()
     ID  A  B    C    D
0  row1  6  7  3.0  8.0
1  row2  4  5  6.0  NaN
```

Solution enhanced by @PierreD:

> This assumes ID is not the index, however (if it is, then it is lost). If you reformulate as pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('ID').last(), then it works in both cases, and makes ID the index. You can of course then .reset_index() if that's not desired.

Comment: Nice, clean and going from first principles. This assumes `ID` is **not** the index, however (if it is, then it is lost). If you reformulate as `pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('ID').last()`, then it works in both cases, and makes `ID` the index. You can of course then `.reset_index()` if that's not desired.

Comment: Thanks @PierreD for your comment. I updated my solution with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming `ID` is the index in both DataFrames** (if not, make it so): There is actually a function [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```py
out = df2.combine_first(df1)
>>> out
      A  B  C    D
ID                
row1  6  7  3  8.0
row2  4  5  6  NaN
```

Notes:

1. why is column `D` of type `float`? Because of that `NaN`.
2. what if the rows are in different order, e.g. `df1` has `row2` first and then `row1`? Not a problem at all and the result is exactly the same as above (with rows sorted). Tested with `pandas=1.4.2` and also `pandas=1.3.4`.

Comment: This might not work if the rows are interchanged in 1st df?

Comment: @PrakashDahal: yes it works regardless of the respective ordering of rows in either `df`.

Comment: @PierreD have you checked it in notebook? It did not work if the row1 and row2 placed are interchanged in df1

Comment: @PrakashDahal Yes. I always check my answers, or if not possible I clearly indicate so. It works with `pandas=1.4.2`, perhaps you have an older version? If you find a version where that didn't work, would you kindly indicate so (and try to find the first where it does work correclty)?

Comment: In first df, `row2 4 5 6` `row1 1 2 3`, In 2nd df, `row1 6 7 8`, is this still working? My version is `1.3.5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246206/discussion-between-pierre-d-and-prakash-dahal).